# UIViewController initialization in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to initialize a subclass of UIViewController that has a corresponding .xib file.

I do it via:

```
LandingVC()
```

However, this doesn't initliaze it with the xib file. I have to do it manually via:

```
LandingVC(nibName: "LandingVC", bundle: nil)
```

What I am confused about is that in Objective-C, I could do this:

```
[[LandingVC alloc] init]
```

and it would automaitcally infer the xib name (if it exists). Why doesn't this work in Swift?

Thanks

Comment: In Objective-C, there is a method - `[[LandingVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandingVC " bundle:nil];` is serving the same purpose.

Comment: Do you have xib named as `Modulename`.`class name`.`xib` ?

Comment: @Mrunal you don't understand my question.. In Objective-C I don't have to do initWithNibName, just init, and it would atomically infer the nib name. In Swift it doesn't do that.

Comment: @rshev I just have a xib named class_name.xib (LandingVC.nib) added to my bundle.

Comment: @0xSina : Okay got your question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To instantiate a View Controller with automatically loading .xib in swift name your xib file as `Module name`.`Class name`.`xib`

It was mentioned in Apple documentation.